# pass list item from c# to javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, list

I have following code to show multiple marker on gmap

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function init() {
            var locations = [
              ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
              ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
              ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
              ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
              ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
            ];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

I want to make this dynamic so i have to pass this

```
 var locations = [
              ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
              ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
              ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
              ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
              ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
            ];
```

from c# code to this js .

I have tried Hidden Field and this code

```
 List<String> oGeocodeList = new List<String>
                                         {
                                            "'Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4",
                                            "'Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5",
                                            "'Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3",
                                            "'Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2",
                                            "'Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1"
                                        };

        var geocodevalues = string.Join(",", oGeocodeList.ToArray());
        ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("locations", geocodevalues);
```

But NO luck any reference will be helpful to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var obj = new[] { 
    new object[] { "Bondi Beach", -33.890542, 151.274856, 4 },
    new object[] { "Coogee Beach", -33.923036, 151.259052, 5 },
    new object[] { "Cronulla Beach", -34.028249, 151.157507, 3 },
    new object[] { "Manly Beach", -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2 },
    new object[] { "Maroubra Beach", -33.950198, 151.259302, 1 },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: I have taken  <input type="hidden" id="hdnLink" runat="server"/> and use same code as you mention and try to set that json string to hidden field and get the hidden field value in js location variable , but marker are not displaying there

Comment: also i matched the hiddedn field value with static ones , both are exact same

Answer (score 7):

Essentially what I believe you're trying to do is create a [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) string. `JSON` allows you to pass objects in a serialized string format between many languages, including JavaScript and C#. I'd recommend taking a look at the [JSON .NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). It's a fantastic library that will allow you to safely and effeciently serialize items to-and-from strings in C#.

I'd also recommend, instead of passing a multi-dimensional array, that you create a more OOP structure. To do this you'll want to create a class for your locations, I'm going to assume the following:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

You'll then want to construct a `List<Location>`, and then serialize that using the JSON .NET library, which will be as easy as this:

```
List<Location> oGeocodeList = new List<Location>() {
    //...
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oGeocodeList);
```

With this JSON, you'll either want to write it to a hidden field, or to a variable within the JavaScript. This will then allow you to reference it on your page through the JavaScript. There is also [pretty comprehensive documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/), which proves very useful!

This can then be accessed in your JavaScript as any other js object, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].Lat, locations[i].Lng),
        map: map
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: But that would output a json like `[{"Name":"Bondi Beach","Lat":-33.890542,"Lng":151.274856},...]`. Not what OP wants.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better reflect that this will not only answer the question, but also applies better coding practices. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think what you can do is create a List.

Example:

```
List<T> data = new List<T>();

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

return serializer.Serialize(data);
```

Thats it.

I hope it work

Comment: You dont even need to reference any other dll.

Answer (score 2):

you must use it something like this:
in your controller:

```
 var locations = [
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];
var locationsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locations);
ViewBag.locationsString = locationsString;
return View();
```

and in your java script use it like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(@ViewBag.locationsString);
```

and you can have your data in array and use it in javascript each function:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
//enter your code
}
```

for javascript not jquery use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       addMarker(data[i], map);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would encode the C# into Json using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) or the C# Json encoder. Then  write it into the hidden field. Then  decode it on the JavaScript side using [Json2](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: you can also write eg `var jsVarialbe = <%= JsonConvert.Serialize(list) %>` ... no need for a hiddenfield