# Access server-side list to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have datarow written from the database.how can I access the list in javascript?
Please help.

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script>");
        sb.Append("var testArray = new Array;");
        foreach (DataRow str in result)
        {
            sb.Append("testArray.push('" + str.ItemArray[1].ToString() + "');");
        }
        sb.Append("</script>");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "test('"PassTestArrayHere"');", true);
```

Comment: Never heard of json? http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826936/pass-list-item-from-c-sharp-to-javascript-array

Comment: One of two ways.  Either 1) render the data to the page when the page loads, or; 2) make an AJAX call to the server from the page to get the data.  The first option is a lot easier unless you have a compelling reason to use the latter option.  What exactly is this code trying to do, anyway?  What does the rendered JavaScript look like and in what way does it fail?

Comment: its failing because of the script tag! I have method that collects data from database and return list and I want to pass it to javascript since i m not using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will not work, instead of using
 `sb.Append("testArray.push('" + str.ItemArray[1].ToString() + "');");` 
you can convert you array to JSON and return to client. In case you still want to follow you approach, you should convert your array to a string with the format like: `String a = "['item0', 'item1', 'item2']";` and then:

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(String.GetType(), "test", "test(" + a + ");", true);`